# get previous close price and %change fields name in Bloomberg Java API

Tags: java, api, bloomberg

I want to retrieve the previous close price and %of change for many securities using Bloomberg java API and i'm asking about their name's field please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can query fields on a Bloomberg terminal with the following command:

```
FLDS WHATEVER_YOU_ARE_LOOKING_FOR
```

In your case, `FLDS PREVIOUS CLOSE` for example.

Which field to use depends on whether you need real time or not: you can either use `PX_CLOSE_1D` or `PREV_CLOSE_VALUE_REALTIME`.

For the % change, you can use `CHG_PCT_1D` or `RT_PX_CHG_PCT_1D` (note that the former does not adjust for dividends whereas the latter does).

Alternatively, you can download the history for those stocks over one day with the appropriate adjustment settings and/or (if you need real time) subscribe to current price and calculate the % change manually.